# Javascript minification of IF condition executing differently

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue with JavaScript after minification. The same code is being executed in a different way. Everything is working as expected before minification. I am unable to understand why this is happening.

**Before Minification**

```
var a = boolAConditionResult();

var b = boolBConditionResult();


if (a && b) {
    doSomething();
}
```

**After minification**

```
a && b && doSomething();
```

I understand that `doSomething()` will be executed only if a and b are true,          but even though a is false (b is true) the `doSomething()` method is being executed in the minified code. Everything works fine in normal un-minified script.

Comment: Is A _false_ as a boolean or maybe a string with "false" written in it?

Comment: please add an example of the missing code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LucaDeNardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124227/luca-de-nardi) was correct in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072711/javascript-minification-of-if-condition-executing-differently/47075870#comment81093480_47072711)

> Is A *false* as a boolean or maybe a string with "false" written in it?

It was false here and "false" there.

Answer (score -2):

try using a ternary operator instead by converting that second double ampersand into a question mark:

```
a && b ? doSomething()
```

Comment: Also, probably, OP doesn't want to check all the minified files and edit them as they should work exactly as the original files.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi that's not an issue, they can just change the un-minified files to be whatever.